# Throws output outside, despite giving stderr=PIPE in python subprocess

Tags: python, pipe, subprocess

```
    str = "blah -l"
    cpuinfo = subprocess.Popen(str.split(),stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)

    tuples = cpuinfo.communicate()
```

In the above code, when I give str=[some_valid_command] gives the output to tuples. When I give an invalid command, I expect the error to be taken to PIPE, but it is still throwing out on the console.... I am not quite sure, where I understood it wrong....

Thanks.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are seeing the stderr actually appear on the console, or are simply running into the Python failure to spawn a process named "blah", which is produced when running the example that you provided...

The output of the example would be Python raising an `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`, which is to be expected unless you have an executable script called "blah" in the PATH

I did a simple test, and wrote a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "This is stdout"
echo "This is a failure on stderr" >&2
exit 1
```

After giving that script executable permissions, I repeated your example but instead called my script (named fail.sh in the local directory) as such:

```
import subprocess

cmd = './fail.sh'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate()
```

This returned `('This is stdout\n', 'This is a failure on stderr\n')` as expected.

So perhaps what you're really seeing here is that whatever program you're trying to call (if it's not blah), simply doesn't exist on your PATH.

Also a note on using `str` as a label in Python: `str` is a built-in type and should not be used as a name for a variable or function, unless you specifically want to "over-load" the built-in function. Same goes for `string`, which is a class.